# Delete Container in POD deployed in AKS using Kubernetes Client Python

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks, windows-container

I am using the following code to kill the container in a pod

```
        from kubernetes.stream import stream
        . . .
        . . .
        # custom function to read downwardAPI generated metadata file which return ns and pod name
        namespace_name, pod_name = pod_metadata.pod_info() 

        # custom function to create CoreV1Api client
        v1 = k8s_client.CoreV1Api()   

        response = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace=namespace_name, field_selector=f"metadata.name={pod_name}")
        command = 'cmd.exe -c "kill 1"'
        command = shlex.split(command)

        for pods in response.items:
            logger.info(f"Pod Name: {pods.metadata.name}")
            for container in pods.status.container_statuses:
                if container.ready:
                    logger.info(f"Shutting down {container.name}")
                    resp = stream(
                        v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                        name=pods.metadata.name,
                        namespace=namespace_name,
                        container=container.name,
                        command=command,
                        stderr=True,
                        stdin=True,
                        stdout=True,
                        tty=False,
                        _preload_content=False,
                    )
                    resp.close()
```

The code is obtained from the following link :- https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1138
The container I have inside POD are windows one. I am not getting any exception and also I dont see container is being killed. I am loading config from kubeconfig.

Comment: there is no kill command on windows. Try taskkill . Something like this ```cmd.exe -c "taskkill /F /PID 1"```

Comment: @apoorvakamath thank you for reply. i am trying to first do it using kubectl. here is my command for kubectl :-
kubectl exec helloworld-deployment-8494f859d5-fnkgt -- cmd.exe -c helloworldcontainer -- echo "hello world" > output.txt
this is a sample kubectl command which should create output.txt inside container but it does on my local box. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @apoorvakamath also i tried this using kubectl :- kubectl exec helloworld-deployment-8494f859d5-fnkgt -- cmd.exe -c helloworldcontainer -- taskkill /F /PID 1 it didnt work. is there anything you would like to suggest?

Comment: Can you give this a try.
```kubectl exec helloworld-deployment-8494f859d5-fnkgt  -c helloworldcontainer cmd.exe -- "taskkill /F /PID 1" ```

Comment: @apoorvakamath same thing...i think first we should try the simplest one like :- kubectl exec helloworld-deployment-8494f859d5-fnkgt -- cmd.exe -c helloworldcontainer -- echo "hello world" > output.txt is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: @apoorvakamath you can reply to this thread for the hello world file creation issue using kubectl exec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761455/execute-command-inside-kubernetes-pod-containing-windows-container

Comment: yes, -c helloworldcontainer is not the argument you want to send to cmd.exe, Its for kubectl to determine your container on which you have to run the cmd.exe.  so it needs to be  ```kubectl exec helloworld-deployment-8494f859d5-fnkgt -c helloworldcontainer  cmd.exe -- echo "hello world" > output.txt```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224347/discussion-between-batman22-and-apoorva-kamath).

Comment: @apoorvakamath i tried it but same result..since i have single container inside tht pod i even removed the container name but same issue

Comment: @apoorvakamath also output.txt is created on my local machine

Comment: @apoorvakamath kubectl exec helloworld-deployment-8494f859d5-fnkgt -c helloworldcontainer  -- ipconfig if i run this it works!

Comment: @apoorvakamath even i changed this in code and that also works